# .tar files without directory structure

Tags: unix, compression, tar

I'm `.tar`ing some files with the path `example/super_user/Output.*`.

The resulting `.tar` looks like this:

```
+ example
    + super_user
          - Output.zip
          - Output.xml
          - Output.txt
```

But I want the file to be like the following:

```
- Output.zip
- Output.xml
- Output.txt
```

Do you know how I can achieve this while still being in another directory?

Comment: Do make sure to avoid [tarbombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)#Tarbomb) with archives like that.

Comment: tar --strip-components=1000 ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

tar will preserve the file and folder structure so I don't think there's any way to instruct tar to flatten the hierarchy at creation time.

One workaround is to temporarily change directory, create the tar, then go back - a quick example below:

```
cd example/super_user && tar -cvf ../../result.tar Output.* && cd ../..
```

Answer (score 56):

If the directory 'example' is at the root of the filesystem, here's another way:

```
tar -C /example/super_user -cvf result.tar .
```

this will change directory to the point that you want to do the tar. The caveat is that if there are any subdirectories under /example/super_user, the directory structure will be preserved for these sub-directories.

Comment: This is the answer to the problem at hand. The mentioned caveat is not a problem in this case. All other answers are workarounds to account for variations to the problem.

Comment: That's indeed the solution to this question. The directory doesn't have to be the root, supposing the directory structure `/home/u/foo/bar`, working dir is `/home/b`, then `tar -C foo/bar -cvf qiz.tar .` works well. One caveat though, is that you can't use wildcards, i.e. `tar -C foo/bar -cvf qiz.tar *.log`, `tar -C foo/bar -cvf qiz.tar "*.log"` or `tar -C foo/bar -cvf qiz.tar "foo/bar/*.log"` won't work.

Comment: It should be noted that you can use `-C` multiple times in a single `tar` command if you need to add multiple files spread over multiple directories but still want the tar file to be flat.

Answer (score 19):

I've posted my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924856/unix-tar-do-not-preserve-directory-structure

repost (for lazy ppl)

---

This is ugly... but it works...

I had this same problem but with multiple folders, I just wanted to flat every files out. You can use the option "transform" to pass a sed expression and... it works as expected.

this is the expression:

`'s/.*\///g'`    (delete everything before '/')

This is the final command:

```
tar --transform 's/.*\///g' -zcvf tarballName.tgz */*/*.info
```

---

Answer (score 10):

To create a tar (ARCHIVE.tar) with all files from a directory (DIR), without any parent directory information (not even ./), you can use something like:

```
find "DIR" -type f -printf "%f\n" | xargs tar cf ARCHIVE.tar -C "DIR"
```

You can play with the find to limit depth, select specific files, and many other things.

Good Luck!

Comment: I'm getting "find: -printf: unknown primary or operator" at OSX find command. Any tips?

Comment: `-printf` is a non standard command. Many of those only work with specific versions of find.  Usually we mark those when answering a question on [SU] (e.g. with "-blah is a Gnu extension and will not work everywhere").

Answer (score 4):

Another way to temporarily change the directory is to put the `cd` and `tar` commands inside the parenthesis `(` `)`:

```bash
    (cd example/super_user; tar -cvf ../../result.tar *)
```

The advantage of this, is, that you will always implicitly pop back to the original directory when the block is done. Another advantage is that the use of the wildcard `*` in this instance, will match the filenames in the temporary directory. i.e. no need for `pushd` .. `popd` blocks or keeping track of where to `cd` back to.

Alternative to the above, there is a special `cd -` command which toggles/undoes the last change directory, e.g.

```bash
    cd example/super_user # change to a subdirectory
    tar -cvf ../../result.tar *
    cd - # undoes the change to the subdirectory
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a temp directory.
And in the directory, created symbolic links to all of the files to the files to be included.
Then I did tar -h -C . so that all the files (not links, but their content) are included in the archive with the desired name.

Answer (score 2):

If those are the entire contents of the tarball then you can use GNU tar's `--strip-components` option to remove the 2 levels before the files.

Comment: I've only got the option `--strip-path` but using it won't change anything.

Comment: This works when a single level stripping is required across all files.

Answer (score 0):

```
pushd example/super_user
tar -cf output.tar Output.*
popd
```

pushd pushes the current directory path to the `DIR` stack and moves to content folder. Then, you move back to original directory by using `popd`.